# Adding Field to Table in design view messes up table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form where I input values that are inserted into a table.

I now want to add a field to the table, but I want it to be a constant value so there is no need to insert anything from the form. For example, whenever a new row is added to the table, the field I want to add just has the constant value.

However, whenever I add the new field in the design view and then try to save it, it says that it cannot find a field with a name that I've never input. But when I remove the constant field that I want to add, there is no problem. Anyone know why?

Comment: It's a difficult question to answer without knowing more specifics about your form. But, it sounds to me like your form *might* be referencing the Table through a query.

On the form, if the `Data` tab on the `Property Sheet` uses a `Record Source` that is not the Table itself, then that can cause some issues. You need to make sure you're adding the column to the table itself, first of all (**not** into a *subform* for instance). Second, figure out what is feeding the table's data into your form.

Comment: What @Jiggles32 said. When you say "whenever I add the new field in the design view," are you designing the form or the table? More details needed.

Comment: Okay, so I am designing the table. The field was added and switching from design view to datasheet is no problem. However whenever I enter a default value for the new field, the error message keeps popping up. I do not understand why, I am not pulling anything from the form to the table for that field. I just want that whenever a new record is added from the form, the field automatically has that constant value.